# Why doesn't this little PowerShell snippet return false?

Tags: powershell

just when I thought I knew PowerShell, I'm wondering what's going on here.  Compare-Object works for both of these examples, and the second example will return the differences if I don't check for $null, but I'm having the worst time doing a simple comparison.  Why does the second example not return **False**?

```
(compare-object @(1,2,3)  @(1,2,3)) -eq $null
```

**True**

```
(compare-object @(1,2,3)  @(1,2,3,4,5,6)) -eq $null
```

**(nothing returned)** - I expect to see **False**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the result is an array, you should check for the count to determine whether there is content:

```
((compare-object @(1,2,3)  @(1,2,3)) | measure).count -gt 0
```

and

```
((compare-object @(1,2,3)  @(1,2,3, 4, 5, 6)) | measure).count -gt 0
```

Comment: I guess that's sort of my issue with this - that I need to make the call to Measure-Object because in the first example, the return value is *not* an array, it's just $null.  I see now that my issue is with the fun way that PS compares arrays to $null.